# about Dev express Grid view runtime error

Tags: asp.net

Microsoft JScript runtime error: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: A field or property with name 'Year' was not found in the selected data source. Possible causes of this error may be the following: an incorrect or case-insensitive spelling of the grid column name; assigning a wrong or not properly initialized data source to the grid`.

i want to bind one datasource to gridview in devexpress it is loaded for first time after that i am applying some more filters with year,month and client then  i will get this error what is the problem the table is showing the data but it is not bind to the Grid please tell me

**Edit**

```
ASPxGridVendor.DataSource = Nothing
ASPxGridVendor.DataBind() 
ASPxGridVendor.DataSource = Session("DSGrid") 
ASPxGridVendor.DataBind()
```

Comment: can any one find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying your filters by posting back, you need to rebind the gridview again with your datasource

Comment: ya i do it in page_init(() method but the error is coming when i debug this the control reaches databind() then it is going to catch block

Comment: ASPxGridVendor.DataSource = Nothing
                ASPxGridVendor.DataBind()
                ASPxGridVendor.DataSource = Session("DSGrid")
                ASPxGridVendor.DataBind()

Comment: In your code, you are setting the datasource into Nothing then Bind this nothing! to your gridview. does this exception occur on first Bind call or on second call?

Comment: first time the grid is loading then i moved to another check box for example month the error is coming second call

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the answer is in the exception message. The column "Year" doesn't exist in the datasource...

Comment: ya but column is not given to grid view